# How to get the url of an <a> tag inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have several iframes in a page (without any ID / classes) generated through a third party advertisement script . I have extracted all the iframe objects through

```
$(document).ready(function($){
$("iframe").each(function(index) {
   console.log(this);
var ur =  $(this).attr('src');
```

Now i need to find the anchor tag  url (ie href) inside this iframe (There is only one anchor tag inside each iframe . Please help .

Comment: Thanks  Tried it , But it is not working , Returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could use the child selector on JQuery to select all anchor tags who are child of an iframe tag.

```
$("iframe a")
```

Or even a direct child selector, if the anchor tag is a first child from the iframe tag.

```
$("iframe > a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the iframe comes from a third party website, then you shall not be able to access the elements inside the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html) of that website through javascript due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Think away from javascript (if possible), fetch the page through PHP/Ruby/Python and then parse the contents, I don't think this can be done browser side. For *how to fetch and parse* in your chosen language you should [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

The short answer to this one is *you can't*, because of the **Same Origin Policy** says that:

> Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first
>   web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web
>   pages have the same origin. An origin is defined as a combination of
>   URI scheme, hostname, and port number.[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html) This policy prevents a
>   malicious script on one page from obtaining access to sensitive data
>   on another web page through that page's Document Object Model.

For anyone reaching this point and wanting to do this on iframes

```
$("iframe").each(function(){
    alert($(this).contents().find("a").first().attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: Yes , It is from a third party website , If we cannot access it through Js / Jquery then what is the alternative . I need just that href string .

Answer (score 0):

Get children (a) of current element (iframe) and get the attribute

```js
var url = $('a', this).attr('href');
alert(url);
```

```html
<iframe withd="50px"> <a href="google.com"></a></iframe>
```